# overlapped column header text in Datatable

Tags: datatables

I use datatable for displaying data and table has 14 columns

but i facing issue in display table header data.It overlapped rather then display in two lines

[image]

I create table like this

```
<table id="tbl" class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="word-wrap:break-word;
              table-layout: fixed;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Column Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

How can i do it in two lines

Comment: Try the following CSS: `table th { word-wrap: break-word; }`. It should help.

Comment: Thankyou..........i try that.. still same issue.. it doesn,t effect @Shashank

Comment: work with this line `word-wrap: break-word;white-space: normal;` @Shashank

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="tbl" class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="word-wrap:break-word;
              table-layout: fixed;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th style="word-wrap: break-word;">Column Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

overfow:hidden should do the trick ;-)

Comment: Better create a css rule for it.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` would hide the overlapping text. `word-wrap: break-word` seems the correct one here. What do you think?

Comment: @Shashank either will work and it will not run into each other.

Comment: True that but I suggested `word-wrap` as the OP asks on how to display the text in 2 lines.

Comment: Anyway, hope one of these 2 styles works out for the OP. :)

Comment: Thankyou @DieterKräutl.. 'overflow:hidden' hide extra characters but still it overlapped to sorting arrows.. i want text in multilines...